# fit randomForest model with cross validation

Tags: python, python-3.6, random-forest, cross-validation

I want to cross validate a random forest model. I did this:
but i didn't know how to fit it.

```
classifier= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)    
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score  
val = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=5)
```

Know to fil the model with cross validation shall i do

```
 val.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `fit`, you should have the `scores` of the 5 folds in `val`

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: Check your `val` variable it should be an `array` with 5 scores one for each `fold`.